# Formatting Dates using a Format class (or otherwise if )

Tags: java

i want to use standard class called `DateFormat` which has subclass `SimpleDateFormat` TO write a method called convert which returns a String in the form dd.mm.yy: when passed a GregorianCalendar with a specific date

```
public String convert (Calendar gc) { ... }
```

For example, when myGC is a `GregorianCalendar` variable representing the 25th of December 2006, `String s = convert(myGC);` should set s to the string "25.12.06".

and i'm having trouble to write a convert method on this

Comment: "I'm having trouble to write a convert method on this" -- perhaps you want to show us what you've tried, and tell us what trouble the code is having?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a pattern like this one `"dd.MM.yy"` in your SimpleDateFormat ?

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
String myDate = dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String convert(Calendar c) {
  return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format(c.getTime());
}
```

Eventually you'll want to store that SimpleDateFormat as a member (for example) if performance becomes a concern.

Comment: ...but watch the concurrency, if it could be an issue (when storing as a member)

Comment: Commons lang has a thread-safe mostly compatible version called FastDateFormat