# how to convert "2012-04-30" date into "04-Apr-2012" format

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting Dates using a Format class (or otherwise if )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065507/formatting-dates-using-a-format-class-or-otherwise-if)

I am using "My Sql" Db, In my DB table,i am storing Date in "2012-04-30" format but now i have to show it in my jsp page in this "04-Apr-2012" format.

How can i do it with Java Code?

Comment: [Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953252/generic-way-to-parse-dates-in-java) and [Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065507/formatting-dates-using-a-format-class-or-otherwise-if) of dates is covered sufficiently on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Date d = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-04-30"));
    String result = (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(d));
    System.out.println(result);
```